# Android Background Application using nonservice objects

Tags: java, android, android-intent, background

I am trying to make a background application for gathering sensor data. I have my sensor manager in an IntentService. But from this service I call the methods from other non service packages. The problem is that my service is destroyed when I get out of the activity.

Is there any solution for that. Can I use non service objects at all?

Here is the code for my service

```
        package tinygsn.services;

import java.io.Serializable;

import tinygsn.beans.InputStream;
import tinygsn.beans.StreamElement;
import tinygsn.beans.StreamSource;
import tinygsn.beans.VSensorConfig;
import tinygsn.controller.AbstractController;
import tinygsn.controller.AndroidControllerListVSNew;
import tinygsn.model.wrappers.AbstractWrapper;
import tinygsn.model.wrappers.AndroidGyroscopeWrapper;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.IntentService;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

public class TestVS  extends IntentService implements SensorEventListener{

    private VSensorConfig config = null;
    private static final String TAG = "ServiceVS";
    public AndroidControllerListVSNew VSNewController;
    public AbstractWrapper w;
    private SensorManager mSensorManager;
    private Sensor mSensor;


    public TestVS()
    {
        super("service");
    }
    public TestVS(String name) {
        super(name);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

      @Override
        protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) 
      {
    //    Log.v(TAG, "Starts Service: " + config.toString());

            Bundle b = intent.getExtras();
            config = (VSensorConfig) b.get("config");


            Log.i("Service", config.getInputStreams().toString());

            for (InputStream inputStream : config.getInputStreams()) {
                for (StreamSource streamSource : inputStream.getSources()) {
                    w = streamSource.getWrapper();
                    Log.v(TAG, w.toString());

                    Activity activity = config.getController().getActivity();
                    mSensorManager = (SensorManager) activity
                            .getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
                    mSensor = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE);
                    mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mSensor,
                            SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);

                    while (w.isActive()) {
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(w.getSamplingRate());
                            ((AndroidGyroscopeWrapper) w).getLastKnownData();
                            Log.i("data read ", "data read");
                        }
                        catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            Log.e(e.getMessage(), e.toString());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
      }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        double x = event.values[0];
        double y = event.values[1];
        double z = event.values[2];

        StreamElement streamElement = new StreamElement(w.getFieldList(), w.getFieldType(),
                new Serializable[] { x, y, z });

        ((AndroidGyroscopeWrapper) w).theLastStreamElement = streamElement;
    }
    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Could you maybe show some relevant code and elaborate? Like this I have no idea what you exactly mean or are trying to do.

Comment: "The problem is that my service is destroyed when I get out of the activity" -- no, it is being destroyed when `onHandleIntent()` ends. `IntentService` is not designed for your scenario. I would suggest that you use a regular service, one in which you use your own background thread(s) for processing sensor data.

Comment: I add the code for my service wrapper package is not a service

Comment: And there is while in the code that it didn't get false so it should not be destroyed